# Multi-camera calibration with opencv: Two cameras facing each other

Tags: opencv, camera, calibration, extrinsic-parameters

I want to compute the extrinsic calibration of two cameras w.r.t each other and am using cv::stereoCalibrate() function to do this. However, the result does not correspond to the reality. What could be wrong ?

Setup: Two cameras mounted 7 meters high, facing each other while looking downwards. They have lot of field of view intersection and I captured checkerboard images that I used in calibration.

I am not flipping any of the images.

Do I need to flip the images ? or do I need to do something else to tell that the cameras are actually facing each other ?

Note: The same function perfectly calibrates cameras that are next to each other facing in the same direction (like any typical stereo camera).

Thanks

Comment: How many images did you use for calibration? Do they have enough rotation variations?

Comment: I am using 50 images with decent rotation and skew variation.

Comment: What I would do: calibrate each camera independtly using `cv::calibrateCamera()`. Estimate the transformation between the two camera frames once they have been definitely fixed: chessboard pattern visible for each camera + `cv::solvePnP()`. The transformation `c1Mc2` can be estimated as `c1Mo x (c2Mo)^-1`.

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify what `c1`, `c2` and `Mo` are. I am assuming `c1` and `c2` are the camera centers and `Mo` is the transformation ? 
`solvePnP()` produces the rotation and translation w.r.t. each camera for each image of the pattern. For example, for a given pattern, lets say we obtain `R1`, `T1` (for the first camera) and `R2`, `T2` (for the second camera) through the `solvePnP()` function. How can we compute `Mo` from these rotation-translation pairs ?

Comment: The notation `c1Mo` corresponds to the homogeneous transformation between the object frame and the camera1 frame : a `4x4` matrix with `(R | T)`. You will have to create `c1Mo` as `R1` is a Rodrigues rotation vector, but basically `c1Mo` is the same as `R1`, `T1`, just a different notation.

Comment: Note also that `(c2Mo)^-1` is the matrix inverse but can be computed more easily as (p72): http://www-lar.deis.unibo.it/people/cmelchiorri/Files_Robotica/FIR_03_Rbody.pdf

Comment: Applied this transform. The result I got was very similar to what I got with `cv::stereoCalibrate()`. The result does not totally resemble the reality, especially in the z coordinate of the translation.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing ? 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to "tell that the cameras are actually facing each other" you have to specify `imagePoints1` and `imagePoints2` correctly, such that points with matching indices correspond to a same physical point.

If in your case function works perfectly when the cameras are oriented in the same direction and doesn't work with your configuration - discrepancy between point indexing might be a probable reason (most likely points are flipped both vertically and horizontally).

One way to debug this is to either draw indices near the points on each of the frames, or color-code them and make sure they match between the images.

One question though - why do you use `cv::stereoCalibrate()`? The setting you described doesn't seem to be a good use-case for it. If you want to estimate extrinsic parameters of cameras you can use `cv::calibrateCamera()`. The only downside is that it assumes that intrinsic parameters are same for all provided views (all images were taken with same or very similar cameras). If it is not the case - indeed `cv::stereoCalibrate()` would be a better fit (but the manual suggests that you still estimate each camera intrinsic parameters individually using `cv::calibrateCamera()`)

Comment: I verified the points and the point correspondences look good. It does not suggest the need of flipping. 
I would like to find the rotation and translation between the first and second cameras which is provided by `cv::stereoCalibrate()`. And yes I am using `cv::calibrateCamera()` to calibrate the individual cameras and am providing the camera matrices to `cv::stereoCalibrate()`.

How do you suggest that I use the results from `cv::calibrateCamera()` to find the transformation between the cameras ?

Comment: Pretty much according to the doc - `objectPoints` will be a vector of vectors of 3d point coordinates of marker, `imagePoints` will be a vector of vectors of detected 2d point coordinates, `rvecs` and `tvecs` will contain extrinsics per each view (rotation and translation). If you can - please provide samples of images with correspondences shown - it will help clear things up.